how do i align my 'fixed' menu nav bar along content wrapper?
How To Resize fixed menu bar?
This is my first time asking here and i hope there is someone who could help me with this issue,Please see image that i have attached.I wanted to resize my menu bar aligned with wrapper and i make the menu bar as fixed.Sorry for my english.
The Code Below


#menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 80px 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #111;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #111), color-stop(1, #444));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: linear-gradient(#a9a9a996, #ffffff00);
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="https://myblabla.com/">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">Bla1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">MyBlaBla</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About Bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="">My Bla Again</a></li>
</ul>




"I wanted to resize my menu bar aligned with wrapper" - what "wrapper"? Please provide a proper [mre] when you ask a question like this, not just tiny snippets that lack all sensible context.

You don't descriptor information clearly. So, it is hardly to support.

Im sorry,Maybe i  do not know how to explain this due to lack knowledge of codes.The image i attached show that i wanted to resize the navigation menu along with content wrapper which my nav menu is fixed,i want the nav menu always on top.The issue is the menu nav are wide width,So i want to resize it along with wrapper.

What do you mean with wrapper? And what should be the goal of the "resize", or what should be the main goal after all? Your comment gives us as much information as your question. Maybe take a tour here too! How to ask?

Then @Deadpool answer should be the working for you

Hope this helps you a bit. Most of the people would just like to close you question. But, I understand what you are trying to want to achieve! Hope htis helps a bit ...!


#menu {
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0; 
    z-index: 9;
    list-style: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#a9a9a996, #ffffff00);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#menu li {margin:5px; position:relative;}
#menu li ul {display:none; position:absolute; width:100px;
background:#ffff99; top:30px;border-radius:5%;}
#menu li:hover ul {display:block;}
<ul id="menu"> 
  <li><a href="https://myblabla.com/">Home</a></li> 
  <li> <a href="#">Bla1</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla1</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla3</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Sub Bla4</a></li> 
     </ul> 
   </li> 
   <li><a href="#">MyBlaBla</a></li> 
   <li><a href="">About Bla</a></li> 
   <li><a href="">My Bla Again</a></li> 
  </ul>



